# Threads - Message Passing

Tags: multithreading, message-passing

I was trying to find some resources for best performance and scaling with message passing. I heard that message passing by value instead of reference can be better scalability as it works well with NUMA style setups and reduced contention for a given memory address.

I would assume value based message passing only works with "smaller" messages. What would "smaller" be defined as? At what point would references be better? Would one do stream processing this way?

I'm looking for some helpful tips or resources for these kinds of questions.

Thanks :-)

P.S. I work in C#, but I don't think that matters so much for these kind of design questions.

Comment: What architecture are you using? SMP, NUMA, Cluster?

Comment: I don't currently have a problem that I am currently solving, but if I was I would be targeting an SMP+NUMA system.

Comment: I think the only sufficient short answer to these questions is, "it depends", and the only sufficient longer answer to these questions is, "benchmark the various options on your target system, and see what kind of performance you get for each one".  Performance depends so much (and often counter-intuitively) on the architectural details of the system you'll be running on that there aren't many general rules that could be applied reliably across systems.  Certainly you shouldn't trust any answer you receive without also measuring it in your app anyway.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner: I was afraid of this. I was hoping more for a "rule of thumb", but this explains why I can't find much info about it. Probably a relatively new threading area. If I don't get any more hits by tomorrow, I'll mark your post for my answer.

Comment: Unless the answer is obvious, (single ints better passed by value, 64K buffers best passed by reference), you should end up trying it as suggested by @JeremyFriesner.  There are some factors that are not immediately obvious, eg: the larger the value copied into a queue, the longer a queue has to remain locked, so increasing contention on the queue.  Give it a go - guesstimate the size of your data, start some threads and throw around some objects. A general assertion that passing by value scales well and reduces contention seems very dubious to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some factors to add to the excellent advice of Jeremy:

1) Passing by value only works efficiently for small messages.  If the data has a [cache-line-size] unused area at the start to avoid false sharing, you are already approaching the size where passing by reference is more efficient.

2) Wider queues mean more space taken up by the queues, impacting memory use.

3) Copying data into/outof wide queue structures takes time. Apart from the actual CPU use while moving data, the queue remains locked during the copying. This increases contention on the queue and leading to an overall performance hit that is queue width dependent.  If there is any deadlock-potential in your code, keeping locks for extended periods will not help matters.

4) Passing by value tends to lead to code that is specific to the data size, ie. is fixed at compile-time.  Apart from a nasty infestation of templates, this makes it very difficult to tune buffer-sizes etc. at run-time.

5) If the messages are passed by reference and malloced/freed/newed/disposed/GC'd, this can lead to excessive contention on the memory-manager and frequent, wasteful GC.  I usually use fixed pools of messages, allocated at startup, specifically to avoid this.

6) Handling byte-streams can be awkward when passing by reference.  If a byte-stream is characterized by frequent delivery of single bytes, pass-by-reference is only sensible if the bytes are chunked-up.  This can lead to the need for timeouts to ensure that partially-filled messages are dispatched to the next thread in a timely manner.  This introduces complication and latency.

7) Pass-by-reference designs are inherently more likely to leak.  This can lead to extended test times and overdosing on valgrind - a particularly painful addiction, (another reason I use fixed-size message object pools).

8) Complex messages, eg. those that contain references to other objects, can cause horrendous problems with ownership and lifetime-management if passed by value.  Example - a server socket object has a reference to a buffer-list object that contains an array of buffer-instances of varying size, (real example from IOCP server).  Try passing that by value..

9) Many OS calls cannot handle anything but a pointer.  You cannot PostMessage, (that's a Windows API, for all you happy-feet), even a 256-byte structure by value with one call, (you have just the 2 wParam,lParam integers).  Calls that set up asychronous callbacks often allow 'context data' to be sent to the callback  - almost always just one pointer.  Any app that is going to use such OS functionality is almost forced to resort to pass by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy Friesner's comment seems to be the best as this is a new area, although Martin James's points are also good. I know Microsoft is looking into message passing for their future kernels as we gain more cores.

There seems to be a framework that deals with message passing and it claims to have much better performance than current .Net producer/consumer generics. I'm not sure how it will compare to .Net's Dataflow in 4.5

https://github.com/odeheurles/Disruptor-net